# Jenkins + Maven + Git Tags - Dependency resolution with build via tags?

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I'm currently in my first month at my first programming job and have been given a few days to see if I can automate our build process with a fresh Jenkins install. I've got it working but need to manually do a few things in Jenkins, like produce specific JAR versions with parameterized builds, and although this works I wanted to automate this further. Thanks for your time in advance!

So, I have a project that uses Maven for dependency resolution. I'm using Jenkins to automate the build process. I've used the git-parameter plugin on Jenkins so that I am able to select tagged versions of the project and sub-projects to build.

The project is dependent on various sub-projects all with their own version tags in git, and the Dev/Prod versions of the main project rely on different versions of these sub-projects, specified in their respective POM files.

**For Example:**

- DEV:  Pom.xml dependent on lib-A 2.0.0 / lib-B 1.5.0.
- PROD: Pom.xml dependent on lib-A 1.0.0 / lib-B 1.0.0.

**lib-A:** Git tags: 2.0.0, 1.5.0, 1.0.0

**lib-B:** Git tags: 1.5.0, 1.0.0

All of the projects exist on a private git repo, and I am able to specify which tagged version to build manually in Jenkins as a parameterised job, to create that version of JAR artifact in the local .M2 repository for DEV and PROD to find. For example, I would manually have to click the parameter 1.5.0 and hit build if I needed lib-A 1.5.0 as a dependency in DEV.

However, is there any way to automate this process so it would be able to resolve the maven dependency versions and send those versions in as parameters to the currently working parameterised builds of the sub-projects?

That is, on a clean machine with my Jenkins configurations I could start a build for DEV and it would:

- git clone DEV, lib-A and lib-B.
- Check pom.xml for versions of lib-A and lib-B
- Send those versions as git-parameter-plugin parameters to build jobs for lib-A and lib-B, to produce the relevant JARs required to compile the main DEV project?

I know this seems pretty vague. but I'm not really troubleshooting a problem, just asking if this is possible and perhaps what it would be called so I can use Google to teach myself how to do it. Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: There is something I don't understand: You probably have a company wide artifact repository (not just the local m2 repository on the Jenkins server). For all release versions, the jars should already be in there. Are you talking about some mechanism for SNAPSHOT versions?

Comment: There's currently no artifact repository, the company is so small that the existing devs have been building and deploying manually so far.

I think there's a way to grab a property from the pom.xml to pass it as a parameter to a parameterised build, looking into that now :)

Comment: Actually, you should have a repository if you build with Maven. It doesn't really make sense to work with (only) the local repository on a Jenkins Server. Have a look at Nexus or Artifactory. We use Nexus, which is pretty easy to handle.#

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. In a nutshell, as long as your jobs all run on the same machine, you can easily access the workplace of job A while running job B (in one of your scripts). There are no security or permission limits of any kind there, and all directory names are static, i.e. no cryptic temporary directories or something like that.

Furthermore, you can have "parent-child"-relationships between jobs (look for `Build other projects` in the job configuration), so the children get fired only after a parent job has run successfully.

As you say that you want to teach yourself, which is highly commendable, I'll leave it at that. Have fun figuring it out from here, or feel free to ask again.

Comment: I've been trying to set that exact pre-build step up over lunch! I read that it's possible to access maven properties from the pom.xml if the build project is a Maven template, so if the parameter I'm looking for is passed as $Version which is the tag from git in the parameterised job then I should be able to set the Version=$lib-A where the lib-A property in the pom.xml is a version number.. Am I on the right path? It's not currently working haha